# How to combine pipes and purrr with {} syntax

Tags: r, purrr, magrittr

I am writing a complex function, but conceptually it is equivalent to

```
A <- 1:3
B <- 10:12
A %>% {purrr::map(B, ~.+.x)}
```

where, in my logic, `.` should be `A` and `.x` should be `B`

The methodology above returns `c(20, 22, 24)` while I want to get `c(11, 13, 15)`.

How do you combine pipes pointing to the lambda function in purrr?

(Please don't suggest me `A %>% +B` ;-))

Comment: Do you need something like `A %>% {purrr::map_dbl(seq_along(B), ~A[.] + B[.])}` ? Or just `purrr::map_dbl(seq_along(B), ~A[.] + B[.])`

Answer (score 1):

`purrr::map2(A, B, ~ .x + .y)` is what you need

Comment: ok, it is actually more difficult than that in the real world problem (apologies)...because A is actually a fixed element, I can't iterate over it. So A can only go in the lambda function

Comment: well you are iterating over it in your example. You can do `A %>% map(B, ~.x + .y, .)` to use the entire `A` in each iteration, but it doesn't give your expected output. I suggest you find a reproducible example that we cannot easily solve with `A + B` ;)

Comment: @DavideTyszui If you don't need to iterate over it you may use it directly like in the comment above or `map(B, ~ .x + A)` if you want to use `purrr`. But this code doesn't produce the same output as you expected (`c(11, 13, 15)`).